# Collectionview jumping when scrolling and using updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition

Tags: uicollectionview

I have a custom collection view, normally it draws fine, scrolling is nice and smooth, generally its okay,

Ive built in the ability to move items around using

beginInteractiveMovementForItem & updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition

To activate beginInteractiveMovementForItem, ive attached it to a long press gesture.

```
@IBAction func longGestureAction(_ sender: Any) { 
        switch longGestureObject.state {

        case .began:
             gridLayout.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)


        case .changed:
             gridLayout.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(longGestureObject.location(in: longGestureObject.view!))

        case .ended:
            gridLayout.endInteractiveMovement()

        default:
            gridLayout.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
}
```

The problem I have is when I drag and the view scrolls, the view jumps, almost like there is an top offset been applied and taken away/ applied - taken away etc

I have my layout class

```
public class ChartGridLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    fileprivate var cache = [[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()

    override public func prepare() {

    cache.removeAll()

    // Calcaulate screen position for object
    // Add it to the cache
    }

    override public var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: calculatedWidth, height: calculatedHeight)
    }

    override public func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
        for attributes in cache {
            for att in attributes {
            if att.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(att)
            }
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override public func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }

    override public func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what would cause my view to 'jump' when dragging items around and page scrolling.

If I just move items around screen (no scrolling) it works perfectly

Ive checked every output from 'prepare' and there is never an offset or anything, it draws smoothly

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `collectionView` instead of `longGestureObject`. So, instead of:

```
gridLayout.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(
    longGestureObject.location(in: longGestureObject.view!)
)
```

use:

```
gridLayout.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(
    longGestureObject.location(in: collectionView)
)
```